# Xpath search on concatenated ancestor vlaues

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file of site structure and would like to search for a node based on concatenated values of that node and its parents.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<site>
    <page id="1">
        <url></url>
        <url>home</url>
        <page id="2">
            <url>about-us</url>
        </page>
        <page id="3">
            <url>locations</url>
            <page id="4">
                <url>scotland</url>
                <page id="5">
                    <url>glasgow</url>
                </page>
                <page  id="6">
                    <url>edinburgh</url>
                </page>
            </page>
        </page>
    </page>
</site>
```

So if the URL was `/locations/scotland/edinburgh` I'd want to select page `id=6`.

I'm hoping the XPath query could be something in the realm of...

```
//page[fn:string-join(ancestor-or-self::page[
                url='locations/scotland/edinburgh'],'/')]
```

Any tips would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need first to split the URL into its path constituents (which can be easily done with XPath 2.0, but not at all in XPath 1.0), then construct and evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
//page[url='locations']
       /page[url='scotland']
          /page[url='edinburgh']
            /@id
```

This selects the required `id` attribute.

**The string value of this `id` attribute (6) is the result of evaluating the following XPath expression**:

```
string(//page[url='locations']
          /page[url='scotland']
             /page[url='edinburgh']
               /@id
       )
```

**Update**:

A single, generic XPath 2.0 expression exists that given a parameter named `$pUrl` that contains the Url, finds all `page` elements with the wanted property:

```
//page
   [ends-with(
              concat('/',
                     string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/url, '/')
                    ),
              $pUrl
             )
   ]
```

**XSLT 2.0 verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'/locations/scotland/edinburgh'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "//page
       [ends-with(
                  concat('/',
                         string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/url, '/')
                        ),
                  $pUrl
                 )
       ]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

<site>
    <page id="1">
        <url></url>
        <url>home</url>
        <page id="2">
            <url>about-us</url>
        </page>
        <page id="3">
            <url>locations</url>
            <page id="4">
                <url>scotland</url>
                <page id="5">
                    <url>glasgow</url>
                </page>
                <page  id="6">
                    <url>edinburgh</url>
                </page>
            </page>
        </page>
    </page>
</site>
```

**the wanted, correct `page` element is selected and output**:

```
<page id="6">
    <url>edinburgh</url>
</page>
```

Comment: is there no way to compare the url string to a concatenated string of each url nodes and their ancestors???? i'd prefer to not have to build a new query each time...

Comment: @IanWood: No, unless you concatenate all `url` attributes first -- this could be done in a single XPAth 2.0 expression, but can't be expressed only with a single XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: ok so concatenating the url part - what would the xpath2 query resemble?

Comment: @IanWood: I updated my answer with the requested single XPath 2.0 expression.